# how to i fomat 4 digit in Arrays.sort(java)

Tags: arrays

I want to output the random number by 4 digit such as 1 = 0001 ,100=0100
but i use String.format i can't run:

```
Arrays.sort(array);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try display the array one by one using for loop:

```
Random rand = new Random(); 

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    array[i] = rand.nextInt(9999);

Arrays.sort(array);

for (Integer s : array) {
       System.out.println(String.format("%04d", s));
    }
```

Comment: but i am a random number :                                                                Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = rand.nextInt(9999) ;

Comment: store your array as string--->  it mean ?

Comment: after:System.out.println( ??)

Comment: if i want to exluding 1111 and 2222 what should i do?

Comment: add if statement to check whether it is 1111 or 2222, if yes don't print, if not then print